# I'm looking for a pokemon fanfic

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, pokemon

I can't remember the summary of the pokemon fanfic or the plot but it's from royal road and I think it could be years ago or just months; my mind is not good at keep track of years

But I remember the cover. It shows a premier pokeball with red line through it (I'm not that familiar that pokemon but I'm interested in the fan-fic) and I think there was a map in the background of the cover.

The story was about being a professor or exploring, again I don't remember the plot very well, or the summary, but there was a gore tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only Pokémon fanfic I could find on Royal Road with a Premier Ball on the cover and a Gore warning tag was this one: [Borne of Caution
by Fuggmann](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/36950/borne-of-caution)

[image]

The synopsis reads:

> An irritated Pokemon might tell you to stop what you're doing. An irritated animal will probably just attack you. Pokemon, for all their power, would be open books and a breeze to care for to any competent animal handler on Earth. After a fiery death, a professional zookeeper who never outgrew Pokemon games ends up in the world of Pokemon. The entire world is thrown onto its side.

Does that ring any bells?